# NSIS: How to delete file matching wildcat pattern in nsis script

Tags: nsis

When users install my software, it creates shortcut on the user's desktop. The name of the shortcut also reflects the version being installed.

It turns out that some of my clients do install multiple versions (although that is no problem, no conflicts or whatever) but it means that user's desktop is bloated with lots of shortcuts for the several various different versions that they have installed over time. (e.g. `SchoolServer 7.1.lnk`, `SchoolServer 7.2.lnk`, `SchoolServer 8.5.lnk` and then the current `SchoolServer 9.0.lnk`)

They have to be deleting these obsolete shortcuts manually.

How can I achieve this in my NSIS script?

Note: I have tried deleting the shortcuts on the desktop with wildcat for all versions and then create the shortcut for the installed version, but it created the new shortcut and still left the old shortcuts there. Code I used is below:

```
;first delete stale shortcuts matching the wildcat
Delete "$DESKTOP\SchoolServer *.lnk"
;create the new shortcut
CreateDirectory "$INSTDIR"
CreateShortCut "${ICON_URL}" "$INSTDIR\SchoolServer.exe" "" "" "" SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED ALT|CONTROL|SHIFT|F5 "SchoolServer"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [SetShellVarContext](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/SetShellVarContext) prior to deleting, to switch to the current user:

```
SetShellVarContext current
Delete "$DESKTOP\SchoolServer *.lnk"
SetShellVarContext all
```

Comment: Genius! But does that not mean that it is advisable to also `SetShellVarContext current` when creating the shortcuts?

Comment: Yes, unless you want to create the shortcut for all users. I'm surprised it's not mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Does that not mean that not setting `SetShellVarContext current` will create the shortcuts for all users? If that is the case, then in my original case, why does not setting `SetShellVarContext current` not delete the shortcuts (recursively) for all users? (instead of failing)

Comment: Good question, I have no idea